# String Conversion error

Tags: c++, string, compiler-construction

I made a struct of strings and every time I try and compare my strings, it says i am comparing ints and chars...but I am only comparing strings?

```
while(gap > 0){
      passOk=true;
      for(int i =0; i < *total-gap; i++)
         if(strcmp(individualf->firstnames[i] , individualf->firstnames[i+gap])>0){
            exchange(individualf[i], individualf[i+gap]);
            passOk = false;
         }
      if(passOk)
         gap /= 2;
   }  
}
```

MY complier error is: cannot convert ‘std::string {aka std::basic_string}’ to ‘const char*’ for argument ‘1’ to ‘int strcmp(const char*, const char*)’

```
      if(strcmp(individualf->firstnames[i] , individualf->firstnames[i+gap])>0){
```

Comment: It looks like you are trying to sort the strings... that's a built-in under C++, see [std::sort](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/sort/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`std::string` has an `operator>`, use it:

```
if (individualf->firstnames[i] > individualf->firstnames[i + gap])
    // stuff
```

If for some reason you must use `strcmp`, then just realize that `std::string` is not a `const char*`, and use `std::string::c_str()` to get a pointer to the `string`'s memory:

```
if (strcmp(individualf->firstnames[i].c_str(), individualf->firstnames[i + gap].c_str()) > 0)
    // stuff
```

Comment: If I declared #include<cstring> and #include<string> and using namespace std; why would I have to use c_str and std:string?

Comment: You don't have to use `std::string`, you just _did_. And because you already did, you must use `c_str()` to be able to use `std::string` with functions that take `const char*`s.

Comment: Using `strcmp()` on an STL string is hackish, IMHO.

Answer (score 0):

You're treating C++ (STL) `std::string`s as old-school C strings. Forget all about C strings and just use the C++ ones.

If you need to compare them, they have a built-in [compare method](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/compare/). If you need to play with case, etc, I highly recommend the [Boost String Algorithms](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/string_algo.html).